# Adding words to Hiragana input's dictionary

Tags: macos, keyboard, dictionary, japanese

I am trying to figure out how to add new words to the Japanese dictionary.

Specifically, my problem is, name of one of my friends is Manaka, spelled 
愛可 (yes, that's 可愛い in reverse).  Problem is, if I type in まなか and try find an appropriate kanji substitute, the only one that I find is 愛花 (and yes, I've tried looking at the general kanji selection, by the reading, by radical,  names, etc).

Currently I type her name in by typing in あいか, which is annoying.

Is there a way to teach the hiragana input, that when I type in まなか I want to see 愛可 as one of the options presented to me?

MacOS X 10.7, MBP 13", English UI with Hiragana input added.

Comment: Doesn't the Kotoeri Word Register do this?  I think you find it toward the bottom of the "flag" menu when Hiragana is active.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Kotoeri Word Register

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do that with the Hiragana Dictionary but how about this:

[image: text replace]

So now each time you type Manaka it will be replaced with  愛可.

EDIT:

According to the official Apple help, you should add the rule replace "まなか" with "愛可". So when you type "まなか" in the Kanji suggestions "愛可" will appear.

> 1. While using a Japanese input mode, choose Edit Text Substitutions from the Input menu in the menu bar.
> 2. In the Text pane of Keyboard preferences, click the Add button .
> 3. In the Replace field, type the hiragana reading of the word (up to 32
>      characters).
> 4. If you add an adjective, enter the reading in its dictionary form.
>
>    - The ending must be 〜い (~i). For example, あたらしい (atarashii) or たかい (takai).
>    - If you add an adverb, don’t include inflective endings, such as 〜な
>        (-na) or 〜だ (-da).
> 5. Click the With column, then type the replacement word (up to 64
>      characters).

Comment: It is a very clever hack, and you are right, normally it would work. Unfortunately this is not really a viable solution in this case, since Japanese has a many words that are pronounced the same way, yet mean a completely different things. In this case, the other kanji for まなか, the one that is actually pretty often used is 真中, middle, centre, midway. And using a code word to substitute in 愛可 is not really any different from typing in あいか、that I do now. Thank you for attempting to help, however.