# How to add a Japanese name that does not appear in the Kotoeri registry? (OS X 10.11)

Tags: macos, text-input, japanese

On OS X 10.11 El Capitan, I am trying to add a word to the Kotoeri lookup dictionary. It is a name that does not come up when you type the Hiragana. The way to do it pre-10.10 no longer works. How can I add the word?

Comment: Not duplicate.  that answer is for pre 10.10 OSX.  Apple changed this so that answer no longer works.  Please remove duplicate tag.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit and use your user dictionaries](https://help.apple.com/jim/mac/10.11/help/index.html?lang=en#/jpim10228) (For OS X 10.11 El Capitan (and 10.10?))

> 1. While using a Japanese input mode, choose Edit Text Substitutions from the Input menu in the menu bar.
> 2. In the Text pane of Keyboard preferences, click the Add button .
> 3. In the Replace field, type the hiragana reading of the word (up to 32 characters).
>
>    - If you add an adjective, enter the reading in its dictionary form. The ending must be 〜い (~i). For example, あたらしい (atarashii) or たかい (takai).
>    - If you add an adverb, don’t include inflective endings, such as 〜な (-na) or 〜だ (-da).
> 4. Click the With column, then type the replacement word (up to 64 characters).

See the [question mentioned as duplicate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143854/adding-words-to-hiragana-inputs-dictionary) for methods for older versions of OS X.

Comment: I tried to add a name using this method and it does not show up.  Is this a bug or does it take time to show up in suggestions?

Comment: It should begin to work immediately. Make sure you entered the correct hiragana for your kanji. Perhaps try restarting.